# CkEditor inserts extra semicolon in Database

Tags: ckeditor

When I add an HTML entity like `&trade;` or `&copy;` in the ckEditor, an extra semicolon is added to it when saving in the database like `&amp;;trade;;`. So the ckeditor displays it as `&amp;;trade;;` and doesn't display the actual trademark symbol.

I don't get it why the extra semicolon is added.

Comment: Can you reproduce it on http://ckeditor.com/demo? Switch to source mode to see what's sent to your database when saving content. I can't reproduce this issue, so most likely it has nothing to do with CKEditor. Check your backend or if you use some custom build of CKEditor (with 3rd party plugins) check CKEditor without them.

Comment: Ckeditor.com/demo displays good. Javascript reads the data fine but in the backend code, before the content is written to the database, it already has the semicolons inserted.

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved. Posting the cause and the solution.

This issue is caused by Tomcat incorrectly attempting to convert XML characters into escaped characters without checking to see if they are already escaped. Resolved by parsing the raw input stream instead of using the HttpServletRequest.getParamter methods. Please explicitly specify the content type as "application/octet-stream" to prevent Tomcat parsing the POST body by default in all the create/edit POST requests.